# How to fix dropdown not working condition

Tags: html, css, navigation, web-deployment, dropdown

I am trying to create a vertical drop-down menu using HTML and CSS but my drop-down is not working. I would like to know where i am going wrong.
I have tried every thing but i am just not getting where i am going wrong

```css
#sidenav {
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #454545;
  font-size: 18px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: fixed;
}

#sidenav input,
#sidenav li,
#sidenav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dropdown-bt {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown-bt:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section id='sidenav'>
  <input type="text" placeholder="search..." id='mysearch' onkeyup="filterSearch()">
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown-bt"><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content" style="display:none;">
      <li><a href="#">-test 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">-test 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">-test 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">-test 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">-test 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">-test 6</a></li>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

For first make `.dropdown-content` as an unordered list, not a div. Remove `style="display:none;"` for the dropdown, you already hide it via css class `.dropdown-content`. Then make the list item `position: relative;` for dropdown positioning.

```
.dropdown-content li {   
   position: relative; 
}
```

And you don`t need a link for dropdown here.

```
   <li class="dropdown-bt">Dropdown
            <ul class="dropdown-content">
                <li><a href="#">-test 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">-test 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">-test 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">-test 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">-test 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">-test 6</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: thanks it worked, but i want to ask whether it is really necessary to use "unordered list' if yes then why

Comment: Now it is not semantic. li should be wrapped by ul tag.
if you don`t need a list, use div instead.
read the documentation https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp and develop semantic layout)